# how to use the generic void pointer of parser tree in ANTLR3

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing a grammar for a simple language using ANTLR3 C target. I want to attach some data 
to the AST generated by ANTLR. As the data to attach is small, using the generic void pointer in `ANTLR3_BASE_TREE_struct` is quite straightforward. The ANTLR3c documentation states that

```
void * u
Generic void pointer allows the grammar programmer to attach any structure they like to
a tree node, in many cases saving the need to create their own tree and tree adaptors.
```

Then I wrote the grammar as below(only a piece of grammar is shown here)

```
datum
@declarations {
    parser_data_t* data;
}
@init{
    data = HPS_MALLOC(sizeof(parser_data_t));
    HPS_RT_ASSERT(data, HPS_ERR_NOMEM);
}
  :  simpleDatum
        {
            data->candidate = 0;
            $datum.tree->u = data;
        }
        -> ^(I_DATUM simpleDatum)
  |  compoundDatum
        {
            data->candidate = 1;
            $datum.tree->u = data;
        }
        -> ^(I_DATUM compoundDatum)
  ;
```

then I generate the lexer/parser, compiled it and linked it to a `main` function. When I ran the program, a segment fault occurred. I checked the parser generated by ANTLR and found the problem. The assignment `$datum.tree->u = data` caused the segment fault because
the data structure `$datum.tree` hadn't been assigned a valid value, so `$datum.tree->u` is an invalid reference.

What I want is to attach some data to the tree node representing the non-terminal `datum`, anyone could tell me how to achieve that? I've searched in google and StackOverflow but no answer found.

Thank you!